# Convert Decision tree from text 2 visual

Tags: python, weka, decision-tree, mallet

I have a decision tree output in a 'text' format which is very hard to read and interpret. There are ton of pipes and indentation to follow the tree/nodes/leaf. I was wondering if there are tools out there where I can feed in a decision tree like below and get a tree diagram like Weka, Python, ...etc does?

Since my decision tree is very large, below is the sample/partial decision to give an idea of my text decision tree. Thanks a bunch!

```
"bio" <= 0.5:
|    "ml" <= 0.5:
|    |    "algorithm" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    "bioscience" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    "microbial" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    |    "assembly" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    "nano-tech" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    "smith" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "neurons" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "process" <= 1.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "program" <= 1.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "mammal" <= 1.0:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "lab" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "human-machine" <= 1.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "tech" <= 0.5:
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    "smith" <= 0.5:
```

Comment: What software produced this text output originally?

Comment: @nekomatic Got this from Mallet: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any tool to interpret that format so I think you're going to have to write something, either to interpret the text format or to retrieve the tree structure using the `DecisionTree` class in MALLET's [Java API](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api).

Interpreting the text in Python shouldn't be too hard: for example, if

```
line = '|    |    |    |    |    "assembly" <= 0.5:'
```

then you can get the indent level, the predictor name and the split point with

```
parts = line.split('"')
indent = parts[0].count('|    ')
predictor = parts[1]
splitpoint = float(parts[2][-1-parts[2].rfind(' '):-1])
```

To create graphical output, I would use [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/). There are [Python APIs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+graphviz) for it, but it's simple enough to build a file in its text-based `dot` format and create a graphic from it with the `dot` command. For example, the file for a simple tree might look like

```
digraph MyTree {
Node_1 [label="Predictor1"]
Node_1 -> Node_2 [label="< 0.335"]
Node_1 -> Node_3 [label=">= 0.335"]
Node_2 [label="Predictor2"]
Node_2 -> Node_4 [label="< 1.42"]
Node_2 -> Node_5 [label=">= 1.42"]
Node_3 [label="Class1
(p=0.897, n=26)", shape=box,style=filled,color=lightgray]
Node_4 [label="Class2
(p=0.993, n=17)", shape=box,style=filled,color=lightgray]
Node_5 [label="Class3
(p=0.762, n=33)", shape=box,style=filled,color=lightgray]
}
```

and the resulting output from `dot`

[image: graphviz tree output]